# Missing Google Search Console data in the Google Data Studio Connector (not in GSC itself)

Tags: looker-studio

I have a few cases of clients that verified their property somewhere in the past year.
To summarize the issue: Google Data Studio has a huge gap in data from say 2 months before the verification, but in GSC itself I can see full 16 months of data. I don't know how to solve this.

You can see the gap in data very clearly on the time series chart (see screenshot). You can also see that Google Search Console itself has the data.

Does anyone else have this issue as well? Did you find a solution or an explanation why this happens?
PS: this is a domain property.

Also: The Data Studio report looks like GSC, because I copied the styling.

[data studio gsc data (problem) vs GSC data (full data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJvQw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong with your data source, but something is clearly wrong with your chart.

Apparently, there is no missing data, but a misaligned data in your X-axis (in the first chart, notice that your data jump from February to July).

[image: Evidence of no missing data]

This usually happens when you choose Line chart over Timeseries chart.  In Line Chart, missing data points aren't plotted (because they don't exist :), but in timeseries chart, missing data points are plotted as zeros.