# Different data from Data Studio and Google Search Console

Tags: looker-studio, google-search-console

I'm really new to Data Studio.

I'm getting weird data from Data Studio, and the data source is Google Search Console.

Data Studio:
[image]

Google Search Console
[image]

Any help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a duplicate of:

- [Missing Google Search Console data in the Google Data Studio Connector (not in GSC itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224499)

Notice how your data jumps from March/2020 to August/2020 in the second chart.

[image: Chart error]

In other words, they're the same data, but GSC is skipping missing data and Data Studio isn't.